# Getting RTTI information about object from within operator new/delete

Tags: c++, new-operator, rtti

Lets say i want to derive everything after following class and i dont assume any further overloading of new or delete:

```
class Object
{
public:
        static map<std::string, unsigned int> typeDeltaMap;
        void* operator new(size_t size)
        {
                void* p = ::new char[size];
                const std::string type = typeid(this).name(); //compile error
                cout << "new type=" << type << endl;
                ++typeDeltaMap[type];
        }
        void operator delete(void* p)
        {
                ::delete(p);
                const std::string type = typeid(this).name(); //compile error
                cout << "delete type=" << type << endl;
                --typeDeltaMap[type];
        }
};
```

And i want to end up with something like this

```
class A : public Object
{
        public:
                virtual ~A(){}
};

class B : public Object
{
        public:
                virtual ~B(){}
};

int main()
{
        A* a = new A();//prints new type=A
        B* b = new B();//prints new type=B
        delete a;//prints delete type=A
        delete b;//prints delete type=B
}
```

I doesnt work as new and delete are static but there are somehow special static as they virtual at the same time.
My question is whether there are some way to obtain such information?

Comment: The only way I can think of is the [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: When `operator new` is called, the object doesn't exist yet. When `operator delete` is called, it has already been destroyed. You need to propagate the type information yourself.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude CRTP doesn't give a common base type, at least not as I know it. The base class of `B` would be `A<B>`.

Comment: @TheVee It seems the OP want the derived type and not the base type, which is exactly what the CRTP provides.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sure, but at the same time they want to store the object via a pointer to the base, see the `main` function.

Comment: @TheVee I don't see it, the only place where the base class is used is for the inheritance specification.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ohh, you're right. I read `A* b = new B()` and thought dynamic polymorphism. Yes, CRTP is good.

Comment: I think it is good enough for my purposes. Thansk @Someprogrammerdude looks like you save the day again :)

Answer (score 1):

As @Someprogrammerdude suggested i've used CRTP which furfills my needs

```
template<typename T>
class Object
{
public:
        ;
        void* operator new(size_t size)
        {
                const std::string type = typeid(T).name();
                cout << "new type=" << type << endl;
                void* p = ::new char[size];
                return p;
        }
        void operator delete(void* p)
        {
                const std::string type = typeid(T).name();
                cout << "delete type=" << type << endl;
                ::delete(p);
        }
};

class A : public Object<A>
{
public:
virtual ~A(){}
};

class B : public Object<B>
{
public:
virtual ~B(){}
};

int main()
{
        A* a = new A();
        B* b = new B();
        delete a;
        delete b;
}
```